# How to send email from a TFS plugin?

Tags: c#, email, plugins, tfs, smtp

I have recently built a TFS plugin PoC that sends email notifications based on certain criteria. For the moment I am sending email by using a gmail account with hard-coded smtp settings. Although this works it obviously isn't acceptable for deployment, and it seems there should be a better way to do this.

I'm wondering if there is a way to leverage TFS to send the email for me, rather than use my own custom email class?

Alternatively I'm wondering if it's possible to for my plugin, which is just a .dll, to use a *.config file to read the smtp settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately what worked best for me was that I was able to put the smtp settings in the web.config located here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config

Then after adding a reference to System.Configuration I was able to read the settings like this:

```
string smtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"];
```

Comment: Did you find a way to override TFS's email event ? I need to do so as I want to send a build success email only on a special case. I coded that special case in the ProcessEvent event

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2013 has built-in functionality for sending email notifications, either to yourself or to the team: [MSDN guide for setting alerts in TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334.aspx)

According to the linked article, you need to:

1. [Configure an SMTP server to cooperate with your TFS server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808.aspx), if you haven't already
2. Open the alerts management page:[image: Alert Drop]
3. If you need to create an alert for the entire team (not just yourself), go to the "Advanced management" page:[image]
4. From here, you can create an alert for new or changed items matching any conditions that you can specify as a work-item query.

Comment: The reason I created a plugin is because there is some custom logic that determines if the length of certain fields is too long to be synchronized with one of our 3rd party tools. Is it possible to create alerts with custom logic?

Comment: You can create alerts for anything you can specify in terms of a work item query. As for your specific case, as far as I know there isn't a built-in way to work item fields based on their length (rather than contents), so no.

Answer (score 1):

i did this in my plugin hosted on codeplex: http://tfswiwatcher.codeplex.com/

Have a look at the code for the TFS 2013 branch. This code is using server api to read the smtp settings from tfs and is using that settings to send mails.

Comment: This looks like a really good suggestion, but you're implementing from INotifyProvider and I'm implemeting from ISubscriber. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how to get access to the WorkItemChangedContext object, which this seems to depend on.